# Modify Skaffold options in CloudCode VSCode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to modify Skaffold options, like --verbosity or --cache-artifacts, at execution time in the CloudCode extension for vscode.

I tried with environment variables, in skaffold.env file, but no success. For example, each time I launch cloucode.kunernetes, I have skaffold running with "-v info" and no "-v debug".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.